# Did Sakura lose her virginity to Kakashi?

Tags: naruto

I read from [here](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2923653/1/Duty-Before-Honor) that for an A-class ranked mission, Sakura teams up with Kakashi, her sensei, and according to the requirement of the mission, she loses her virginity to Kakashi.

Is this story true? Had it actually happened in the manga?

Comment: That's fan fiction... therefore not canon.

Comment: @user14856 last line of the first chapter seems to indicate that Sakura is looking to loose her virginity in order to be accepted for a mission in which things could take a turn for the worse in which she may need to do something involving sex and that if she was a virgin it may be traumatic for her to loose it there. Manga wise Sakura probably looses it to Sasuke after they get married though we wouldn't know all the details on how many times they did it before Sarada was concived

Comment: This is apparently the first result that comes up if you search "who took Sakura's virginity" on Google.

Answer (score 17):

Canon information about Sakura does not anywhere mention her losing her virginity to Kakashi, nor her being sexually-involved with him in any form. See some of the following profiles:

- [Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sakura_Haruno)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakura_Haruno)
- [Japanese Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%98%A5%E9%87%8E%E3%82%B5%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9)

Same goes for Kakashi profiles:

- [Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake)
- [Japanese Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%91%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B7)

Since the event did not occur in manga canon, no page reference can be provided. Sakura's virginity, or lack thereof, is not unmistakably specified in canon. In [manga chapter 700+1](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sarada_Uchiha_(chapter)) titled *Uchiha Sarada*, it is evidenced that Sarada has believed Sakura to be her biological mother and Sasuke to be her biological father, so it *implies* that Sakura lost her virginity at some unspecified point (unless she used IVF technology). However, Sarada *subsequently questions* whether Sakura is indeed her biological mother; this is debated by fans in threads such as [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:168274), [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:168203), and [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:169667). Sarada's doubt about biological ties to Sakura means that canon has not uniquivocally defined whether or not Sakura has ever been sexually active or pregnant.

[*Duty Before Honor*](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2923653/1/Duty-Before-Honor) is an English-language fanfiction written by [SilverShine](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/524424/SilverShine) with a Kaka/Saku [ship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipping_%28fandom%29) (a.k.a. pairing). The [reader reviews](https://www.fanfiction.net/r/2923653/) for the fanfic indicate that the premise was created to be an [AU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_universe_%28fan_fiction%29) (alternate universe) rendition of the characters crafted by SilverShine. [*Stripped Bare*](http://archiveofourown.org/works/443225/chapters/757443) is also an English-language fanfiction, written by [Purple_Panic](http://archiveofourown.org/users/Purple_Panic/pseuds/Purple_Panic) (formerly known as [J-Pop Princess](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/1277173/J-Pop-Princess)); its reader reviews are [here](http://archiveofourown.org/works/443225/chapters/757443). [Fanfiction.net](https://www.fanfiction.net/guidelines/) and [Archive of Our Own](http://archiveofourown.org/about) are both fanfiction repositories. As such, they do not feature canon material and are not intended to serve as a source of information about canon; in contrast, fanfiction and *doujin* works tend to create content that is original or intentionally contradicts canon. Kaka/Saku (written as カカサク, or カカシ×サクラ) is [not a prominent ship in Japanese doujinshi](http://auctions.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?auccat=&p=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%80%80%E3%82%B5%E3%82%AF%E3%80%80%E5%90%8C%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%8C&tab_ex=commerce&ei=utf-8).

Comment: not fully understanding those kind of things as all i know is that there is some membrane which represents a girls' virginity, wouldn't Sakura still loose her virginity when she gives birth since said membrane would be broken during child birth?

Comment: @Memor-X, I have updated the answer since it is not clear whether or not Sakura gave birth (even if she did, it could have been by C-section). The concept of virginity is not about the status of the [hymen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hymen) (some women are not even born with the sort that is able to tear. Sakura could easily have torn hers at any point during non-sexual physical exercise), but about the state of never having engaged in sexual intercourse: often considered to be vaginal, but [varies by culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginity#Definitions_of_virginity_loss).

Comment: Hymens can be stretched by [Kegel exercise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kegel_exercise) prior to 1st tampon use or 1st sexual intercourse, so some woman/girls do not need to experience any tearing. Natural childbirth is not generally considered to be any sort of sexual intercourse, to be innately sexual or even sensual, so a hymen incidentally tearing for the first time during the birthing process (such as in cases of IVF, surrogacy, etc.) would not generally be considered to constitute "losing virginity" even under many cultural definitions of virginity that take the hymen into account.

Answer (score 1):

In the canon manga, it's confirmed Sasuke and Sakura have a child together, hence her losing it to Sasuke. Kakashi and Sakura have never been sexually active together.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question but I also don't see how someone having a kid with someone proves that they lost their virginity to that same person.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Kakashi has saved girls' life rapidly over the years like Rin. He rescued her, but later on, she made him killed herself.

If Kakashi had intercourse with Sakura, that's like a teacher having intercourse with a student. If she was over 18, it's fine, but it makes people worried because in *Boruto*, there is a kid that is like Kakashi but with brown hair and pink and white hair, making a brownish rose color. So they could be parents.